# Basic Isabelle sequence limit proof

Tags: isabelle, proof, theorem-proving

As hundreds have tried before me, I'm trying to learn Isabelle by attempting to prove extremely basic mathematical theorems. The task is hard because most Isabelle tutorials and books focus, for some reason, on program analysis (lists, trees, recursive functions) or elementary propositional/first-order logic and the exercises therein can largely be solved by `(induct_tac "xs")` and a couple of apply statements.

However, by digging through pages and pages of existing Isabelle theories, I have figured out how to define something. In this case, I defined the limit of a sequence:

```
theory Exercises
  imports Main "Isabelle2019.app/Contents/Resources/Isabelle2019/src/HOL/Rat"
begin

definition limit :: "(nat ⇒ rat) ⇒ rat ⇒ bool"
  where limit_def: "limit sequence l = (∃(d::nat). ∀(e::nat)≥d. ∀(ε::rat). abs((sequence d) - l) ≤ ε)"

end
```

Then I tried to prove that `lim 1/n --> 0`. (sorry, Latex doesn't work on Stack Overflow).

The proof I had in mind was quite simple: give me an `epsilon`, and I'll show you a `d` after which `1/d < epsilon`. However, I'm stuck after a couple of most basic steps. Could I get a hint on how to complete this proof?

```
lemma limit_simple: "limit (λ (x::nat). (Fract 1 (int x))) (rat 0)"
  unfolding limit_def
proof
  fix ε::rat
  obtain d_rat::rat where d_rat: "(1 / ε) < d_rat" using linordered_field_no_ub by auto
  then obtain d_int::int where d_int: "d_int = (⌊d_rat⌋ + 1)" by auto
  then obtain d::nat where "d = max(d_int, 0)"
end
```

As maybe visible from the very first lines of this proof, I am already stuck trying to convince Isabelle that there is a natural number `d` that is greater than `1/epsilon` for every rational `epsilon` ...

Comment: The reason why the tutorials for beginners tend to focus on more functional programming-style things is because that is just much easier and you don't get frustrated as quickly.

Comment: Also, are you aware that Isabelle's library already provides a large library of analysis, including of course the notion of a limit? (besides, it is much easier to write `1 / of_nat x` instead of `Fract 1 (int x)`. Moreover, I would work directly with the `real` type, not `rat`. For some reason, `rat` is not used often in Isabelle)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I do realize that Isabelle already includes a large analysis library, but if I wanted to build proofs based on that which are not already in Isabelle, I'd have to tackle Isabelle simultaneously with mathematical concepts that are actually hard. Instead, I'm trying to prove something super basic, which allows me to focus on Isabelle, but of course the extremely basic theorems are already built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, your definition of `limit` is wrong. You mixed up the quantifier order a bit. Here's how I would write it:

```
definition limit :: "(nat ⇒ rat) ⇒ rat ⇒ bool"
  where "limit sequence l = (∀ε>0. ∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦sequence e - l¦ ≤ ε)"
```

And then here is how one could prove the thing you wanted:

```
lemma limit_simple: "limit (λ(x::nat). 1 / of_nat x) 0"
  unfolding limit_def
proof (intro allI impI)
  fix ε :: rat assume "ε > 0"
  obtain d_rat::rat where d_rat: "1 / ε < d_rat" using linordered_field_no_ub by auto
  define d where "d = nat (⌊d_rat⌋ + 1)"

  have "d_rat ≤ of_nat d"
    unfolding d_def by linarith

  from ‹ε > 0› have "0 < 1 / ε" by simp
  also have "1 / ε < d_rat" by fact
  also have "d_rat ≤ of_nat d" by fact
  finally have "d > 0" by simp

  have "d_rat > 0" using ‹1 / ε > 0› and d_rat by linarith

  have "∀e≥d. ¦1 / of_nat e - 0¦ ≤ ε"
  proof (intro allI impI)
    fix e :: nat
    assume "d ≤ e"
    have "¦1 / rat_of_nat e - 0¦ = 1 / rat_of_nat e" by simp
    have "d_rat ≤ rat_of_nat e"
      using ‹d ≤ e› and ‹d_rat ≤ of_nat d› by simp
    hence "1 / rat_of_nat e ≤ 1 / d_rat"
      using ‹d ≤ e› and ‹d > 0› and ‹d_rat > 0›
      by (intro divide_left_mono) auto
    also have "1 / d_rat < ε"
      using ‹ε > 0› and ‹d_rat > 0› and d_rat by (auto simp: field_simps)
    finally show "¦1 / rat_of_nat e - 0¦ ≤ ε" by simp
  qed
  thus "∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦1 / of_nat e - 0¦ ≤ ε"
    by auto
qed
```

The proof would look basically the same for real numbers instead of rational ones. It could certainly be automated a bit more (well, if you import Isabelle's analysis library, it can prove the entire thing automatically in a single step).

In ‘real world’ Isabelle, limits are expressed with *filters*, and there is a large library around them. This makes proving statements such as the above much less tedious.

**Update:** Responding to your comment: Yes, this is a bit lengthy. In idiomatic Isabelle, I would write the proof something like this:

```
lemma A: "filterlim (λn. 1 / real n) (nhds 0) sequentially"
proof
  fix ε :: real assume "ε > 0"
  have "∀⇩F n in sequentially. n > nat ⌈1 / ε⌉"
    by (rule eventually_gt_at_top)
  hence "∀⇩F n in sequentially. real n > 1 / ε"
    by eventually_elim (use ‹ε > 0› in linarith)
  moreover have "∀⇩F n in sequentially. n > 0"
    by (rule eventually_gt_at_top)
  ultimately show "∀⇩F n in sequentially. dist (1 / real n) 0 < ε"
    by eventually_elim (use ‹ε > 0› in ‹auto simp: field_simps›)
qed
```

This concept of filters and a property holding ‘eventually’ (that's what this `∀⇩F` syntax means) is very powerful.

Even better, you can modularise the above proof a bit more into first showing that 1/`x` tends to 0 for `x`→∞ for a real `x`, and then show that `real n` tends to real ∞ for `n`→∞ for a natural `n` and then simply combine these two statements:

```
lemma B: "filterlim (λx::real. 1 / x) (nhds 0) at_top"
proof
  fix ε :: real assume "ε > 0"
  have "∀⇩F x in at_top. x > 1 / ε"
    by (rule eventually_gt_at_top)
  thus "∀⇩F (x::real) in at_top. dist (1 / x) 0 < ε"
    using eventually_gt_at_top[of 0]
    by eventually_elim (use ‹ε > 0› in ‹auto simp: field_simps›)
qed

lemma C: "filterlim real at_top sequentially"
  unfolding filterlim_at_top
proof
  fix C :: real
  have "∀⇩F n in sequentially. n ≥ nat ⌈C⌉"
    by (rule eventually_ge_at_top)
  thus "∀⇩F n in sequentially. C ≤ real n"
    by eventually_elim linarith
qed

lemma D: "filterlim (λn. 1 / real n) (nhds 0) sequentially"
  by (rule filterlim_compose[OF B C])
```

Or, of course, you can simply import `HOL-Real_Asymp.Real_Asymp` and then all of these are done automatically using `by real_asymp`. ;)

You really should not judge a system by how difficult it is to do everything from scratch, especially when there is an established idiomatic way of how to do them and you are actively doing something different. The standard library and its idioms are an important part of the system.

It is difficult to emulate pen-and-paper-style reasoning in a proof assistant, especially in an area like asymptotics where many things are ‘obvious’. Luckily, with a good library, some approximation of that kind of reasoning can indeed be achieved. You *can* do explicit ε-δ-reasoning if you want to, of course, but it's just going to make your life more difficult. I made the same mistake when I started working with limits in Isabelle (because ε-δ is the only formal way to treat limits that I knew and I didn't understand all that fancy filter stuff), but as soon as I started understanding filters more, things became much clearer, easier, and more natural.

Comment: Ooph! This is WAY longer than I thought --- considering how extremely short a "human" proof would be even in introductory math textbooks. I'm going to try to follow your proof line by line and always guess the next line ...

Comment: I updated my answer a bit to show how to do this in a more concise way.

Comment: Your answer has already been extremely helpful. Yesterday I also tried to prove that (Sum_i i)^2 = Sum_i i^3, which again posed a number of problems because Isabelle is very slow and unhappy to unify long sums involving stuff like "1/4 n^2 (n +1)^2 + (n+1)^3 = 1/4 (n^4 + 6n^3 + 13n^2 + 12n + 4)" (I hope I copied that correctly from my handwritten notes)

Comment: I wonder if it would be possible to write a tutorial on proving basic mathematical theorems like the above and the HM GM AM QM inequalities using a couple of methods such as Cauchy Schwarz and Lagrange multipliers in Isabelle ... this would likely lower the entry hurdle drastically

Comment: My experience with Isabelle is mixed insofar as I have been impressed what complicated stuff can be proved using the system, but also a bit disappointed that expressing many extremely basic chains of reasoning requires either many complicated and unintuitive steps or extremely extensive knowledge of the Isabelle libraries ...

Comment: Isabelle is probably great and extremely useful to show that the foundations of math are sound. However, I think Isabelle and related systems could do so much more for math if they simultaneously enabled or even assisted "regular" mathematicians, and even "doofuses" from the industry like me, to formulate and prove basic theorems

Comment: Currently it feels like I have to assist Isabelle, not the other way around

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of the difficulties here come from all the conversions between `nat` and `rat`. It is easier to prove the limit for an equivalent function on the rationals:

```
definition limit_r :: "(rat ⇒ rat) ⇒ rat ⇒ bool"
  where "limit_r sequence l = (∀ε>0. ∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦sequence e - l¦ ≤ ε)"

lemma limit_simple_r: "limit_r (λx. 1 / x) 0"
 unfolding limit_r_def
proof (intro allI impI)
  fix ε :: rat assume "ε > 0"

  hence "¦1 / (1/ε) - 0¦ ≤ ε"
    by auto

  hence "∀e≥(1/ε). ¦1 / e - 0¦ ≤ ε"
    using `ε > 0` by (auto simp add: divide_le_eq order_trans )

  thus "∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦1 / e - 0¦ ≤ ε"
    by blast
qed
```

The results can then be transferred back to sequences:

```
definition limit :: "(nat ⇒ rat) ⇒ rat ⇒ bool"
  where "limit sequence l = (∀ε>0. ∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦sequence e - l¦ ≤ ε)"

lemma to_rat_limit:
  assumes a1: "limit_r sequence_r l"
    and a2: "⋀n. sequence n = sequence_r (of_nat n)"
  shows "limit sequence l"
  unfolding limit_def proof (intro allI impI)
  fix ε :: rat
  assume "0 < ε"

  from assms obtain d where "∀e≥d. ¦sequence_r e - l¦ ≤ ε"
    using ‹0 < ε› using limit_r_def by blast  

  hence "¦sequence e - l¦ ≤ ε" if "e ≥ nat ⌈d⌉" for e
    using that a2 by (auto, meson of_nat_ceiling of_nat_mono order_trans)

  thus "∃d. ∀e≥d. ¦sequence e - l¦ ≤ ε"
    by blast
qed


lemma limit_simple: "limit (λ(x::nat). 1 / of_nat x) 0"
  using limit_simple_r to_rat_limit by auto
```